# alert dialog button not working when created with generic dialog flutter

Tags: flutter, android-alertdialog

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gequv.png)

i have created a generic dialog that can create buttons that return some values

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef DialogOptionBuilder<T> = Map<String, T?> Function();

Future<T?> showGenericDialog<T>({
  required BuildContext context,
  required String title,
  required String content,
  required DialogOptionBuilder optionBuilder,
}) {
  final options = optionBuilder();
  return showDialog<T>(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text(title),
        content: Text(content),
        actions: options.keys.map((optionTitle) {
          final value = options[optionTitle];
          return TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              if (value) {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(value);
              } else {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              }
            },
            child: Text(optionTitle),
          );
        }).toList(),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

and when i try to use this generic dialog to create a simple alert dialog that has a button "ok" this "ok" button is not poping out the alert dialog even though i have coded to popout the dialog when no value is returned from the dialog when a button is pressed

```
Future<void> showCannotShareEmptyNoteDialog(BuildContext context) async {
  return showGenericDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    title: 'Sharing',
    content: "You can't share a empty note",
    optionBuilder: () => {
      'OK': null,
    },
  );
}
```

in here i'm calling the alert dialog

```
appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("New Note"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final text = _textController.text;
              if (_note == null || text.isEmpty) {
                await showCannotShareEmptyNoteDialog(context);
              } else {
                Share.share(text);
              }
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.share),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: its quite confusing, **"ok" button is not poping out the alert dialog** ? this will make your dialog infinite loop, because when no value, its show dialog again and again. 
you have to separate it

Comment: ok button is not removing the alert dialog from the screen

Answer (score 0):

> ok button is not removing the alert dialog from the screen

thats because your condition below throw exception. since your type is `void` no value returned.

```
...
 return TextButton(
    onPressed: () {
       if (value) {  // this one is caused the error. because its null. not bool
          Navigator.of(context).pop(value);
       } else {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
       }
```

error:

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═════════
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'
```

change to this:

```
return TextButton(
  onPressed: () {
    if (value == true) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop(value);
    } else {
      print(value);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
  },
```